# How can the django admin url pattern be modified so the links have unique urls?

Tags: django, django-models, oracle11g, legacy

I'm trying to add oracle legacy tables that has no pk but a composite pk, only which are unique together, to django admin. When inspecting the URLs to make the change to the objects, they are all the same. Django can't auto create a pk id because oracle will throw an error. This forces one of the fields to be pk which isn't unique, causing get() return more than 1 row. Several issues or requests

1. How can more fields be added to get so it doesn't just use the arbitrary pk.
2. The fields can be concat in **str** which shows the pair in the view but where else can I store this pair so it can be passed to get the unique object for change.
3. If meta unique_together is set, how can I tell the queryset to use this pair and not the arbitrary pk when building the model list.

Comment: Show us your view. Basically it needs to receive two parameters (your two keys) and your queryset should just filter on both. A path like `/models/<int:pk>/<str:uid>` as url would pass `pk` and `uid` to your view.

Comment: I'm not using the views yet to build query. I am still using the admin interface. When clicking on the registered model link to look model list, the inspect shows series of /<app>/<model>/<str:pk>,/<app>/<model>/<str:pk>,/<app>/<model>/<str:pk>,/<app>/<model>/<str:pk>. Because I do not have a primary key but a composite primary key, I cannot figure out how to tell Django admin to override their get_queryset or get_object().

Comment: my further research leads me to modify get_urls() through ModelAdmin. I hope this leads me to the right direction.